# How to handle Firebase permission denied exception gracefully

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Is there any way to avoid permission_denied exception dump on console. I dont want to see that exception on console and want to handle it gracefully. I tried follownig but it does not seems to be working. I also tried .onAuth() but that also does not prevent this happening.

```
var ref = new Firebase(<My firebase root url>),
 ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
     console.log("No errors.");
 }, function(err) {
     console.log("Something is wrong. "+err);
 });

Something is wrong. Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
SearchCtrl.js:22 User Not Authenticated..Redirecting to Sign In Page...
ionic.bundle.js:19532 Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.
    at Error (native)
    at J (http://localhost:8100/lib/firebase/firebase.js:120:48)
    at Object.J (http://localhost:8100/lib/firebase/firebase.js:200:378)
    at http://localhost:8100/lib/firebase/firebase.js:185:3
    at vh.h.Hd (http://localhost:8100/lib/firebase/firebase.js:189:104)
    at jh.Hd (http://localhost:8100/lib/firebase/firebase.js:180:364)
    at bh.jh.Da.uh.t [as tg] (http://localhost:8100/lib/firebase/firebase.js:178:281)
    at eh (http://localhost:8100/lib/firebase/firebase.js:172:464)
    at WebSocket.bh.open.va.onmessage (http://localhost:8100/lib/firebase/firebase.js:171:245)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:19532c.$$error @ angularfire.min.js:12(anonymous function) @ angularfire.min.js:12(anonymous function) @ angularfire.min.js:12forEach @ ionic.bundle.js:8248g @ angularfire.min.js:12(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:24148completeOutstandingRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:12830(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:13210
ionic.bundle.js:19532 destroy called for FirebaseArray: https://fixmycars.firebaseio.com/customers
ionic.bundle.js:19532 TypeError: Cannot read property '$$error' of null
    at angularfire.min.js:12
    at angularfire.min.js:12
    at Object.forEach (ionic.bundle.js:8248)
    at g (angularfire.min.js:12)
    at ionic.bundle.js:24148
    at completeOutstandingRequest (ionic.bundle.js:12830)
    at ionic.bundle.js:13210(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:19532$get @ ionic.bundle.js:16482(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:24151completeOutstandingRequest @ ionic.bundle.js:12830(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.js:13210
```

Comment: The correct answer here is generally to make sure the user has correct permissions before accessing the data. In most cases, you can consider it a bug if your client attempts to access data without permissions. Since you are logging the error to console, it seems pretty straightforward to remove the log of the error message. Also, a good read-through of [the guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/) is going to save you, and Stack Overflow a lot of thrashing.

Comment: This exception is not  because of the err object that i am trying to display. I even tried removing that object, and i can still see that exception. After that line executes it just go back and forth in firebase.js and ionic-bundle.js and finally from ionic-bundle.js the method "self.defer " which throws that exception..

Comment: Look like you have an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Answer (score 3):

Parse the error and/or create a match rule to handle all errors that you would like to handle. Place the handlers inside the else statement in you current structure.

```
var ref = new Firebase(<My firebase root url>),
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.exists()){
        /*Update dom or kick of async method to mount snapshot*/
    }else{
        app.$.errorToast.text = 'Snapshot does not exist';
        app.$.errorToast.show();
    }
    console.log("Did I forget to handle an error");
}, function(err) {
    /*Compare "err" to your rules and handle as needed here*/
    console.log("Something is wrong. "+err);
});
```

Where ever in your code you attempt to complete an action that is not permissive the ".on" function will fire and handle as defined in the single codeblock above.

To provide good resolution messages to the client such as "The current user is not permitted to access, to gain access contact admin and request user id be added to permission group {myRefMeta.permgroup}". One option I have considered is maintaining another branch that describes the permissions or add a public accessable "descriptor" of the branch in the base node that provides the security details.This knowledge of the user and a discriptor of the tree you are working with you will be able to eliminate this error before it happens.

In the case that the user logs out and the cache is not cleared your ref.on event will fire again. When this happens you should take care to clear the cache and complete a full reload. This is possible by forcing a refresh of the browser after the cache is cleared.

In this code block above the errors are handled in the ref.on and the ref.on will never reach the call to remount the snapshot or update the DOM. By calling a cleanup method in your error handler you can mount an empty snapshot, reset your references and disable features that are not available.

It is optimal for my purposes to wait until permission is needed to request it from a user and by creating a convenience function "referenceCheck" you can use this to kick off authentication and reference creation as needed. This will act as an init method for the "usecase" and the cleanup for that use case will be oh so complimentary to this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are adding the permission_denied exception dump on console yourself.
Do not add the "err" in console log in your error handler function,
e.g. console.log("Something is wrong. "+err);

Comment: This exception is not  because of the err object that i am trying to display. I even tried removing that object, and i can still see that exception. After that line executes it just go back and forth in firebase.js and ionic-bundle.js and finally from ionic-bundle.js the method "self.defer " which throws that exception..