# In firebase, can client know the reason when getting permission deny?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Firebase uses rules to protect and validate data. When a client try to save  some data which is invalid, the client only get a [PERMISSION DENY] error without any extra information. It's inconvenience for the app to show proper message, guiding the user to fix his data.

Is there any way that the client side can receive any extra information when getting permission deny?

---

Update:
For example, let's say that each user has a simple profile saved in Firebase database like this:

```
data
+- userProfile
   +- $uid
      +- name: Alex
      +- message: "Hi, everybody!"
      +- updatedAt: 1484406052268
```

The user, Alex, can change his short message and my app should try to save the message as `message` and set `updatedAt` to the current time.

On the other hand, the security rule somehow looks like this:

```
"$uid":{
  ".validate": "newData.hasChildren(['name', 'message', 'updatedAt'])",
  "name":{
    ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length <= 30"
  },
  "message":{
    ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length <= 72"
  },
  "updatedAt":{
    ".validate": "newData.val() < now"
  }
}
```

There is a restriction that the length of message should be less than 72, as well as a protection that the value of `updatedAt` is reasonable.

Now, if Alex get a [PERMISSION DENY] from the database, how can he (or how can my app) tell that whether he wrote an overlength message, or he should set his clock on his mobile correctly and try again?

Comment: Errors are handled in code so without knowing your use case or seeing code, it's impossible to provide an accurate answer.

Comment: Information about what security rule failed is not passed from the database servers to the client. To give your users a better error message, you should validate the data client-side too.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30022331/how-to-handle-firebase-permission-denied-exception-gracefully/38156620#comment48188032_30022331, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349895/firebase-is-there-any-way-to-customise-firebase-rules-permission-error-message and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35252101/how-can-i-know-what-security-firebase-rule-give-me-a-error/35255673#35255673

Comment: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen !